# How many possibilities are there to distribute $8$ students to $5$ round tables, if minimum $1$ student sits at each table?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many possibilities are there to distribute $8$ students to $5$ round tables, if minimum $1$ student sits at each table? It is irrelevant, which table is allocated to which group.

I think that there are $3$ possible distributions:

1) 4-1-1-1-1

2) 3-2-1-1-1

3) 2-2-2-1-1

So I have for the first case (I divide by $4$ because the table is round so I have to remove the renundant possibilities):

$Perm_4(8) \cdot \frac{1}{4} = \frac{8!}{(8-4)!} \cdot \frac{1}{4}$

second case:

$Perm_3(8) \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot Perm_2(5) \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{8!}{(8-3)!} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{5!}{(5-2)!} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$

third case:

$Perm_2(8) \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot Perm_2(6) \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot Perm_2(4) \cdot \frac{1}{2} = \frac{8!}{(8-2)!} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{6!}{(6-2)!} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{4!}{(4-2)!} \cdot \frac{1}{2}$

so in sum:

$ \frac{8!}{(8-4)!} \cdot \frac{1}{4} + \frac{8!}{(8-3)!} \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \frac{5!}{(5-2)!} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{8!}{(8-2)!} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{6!}{(6-2)!} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{4!}{(4-2)!} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = 4060$

which is wrong. The correct solution is $1960$. How can I achieve that?

Comment: I think the problem is in the third case, you count many times the same configuration.

Comment: Does students' identity matter?

Comment: The Task aks for sitting combinations. So I think yes.

Comment: There are, for example, more than 4 ways to seat 4 students at a table. You are adjusting for the fact that `abcd`, `bcda`, `cdab`, and `dabc` are all equivalent (differing only by where on the circle you start counting), but it sounds like a permutation like `acbd` should *also* be counted as an equivalent seating.

Comment: For case 3: Pick the six students who will be sitting at a table with another student: $\binom{8}{6}$ choices.  From among these students, one will be youngest.  Pick who happens to be seated with that youngest student: $5$ choices.  Having removed those two, there will be a new youngest remaining, pick who sits with him: $3$ choices.  There are then $\binom{8}{6}\cdot 5\cdot 3 = 420$.  Your answer came to $2520, causing the problem

Comment: For case 2: Pick the three students who sit together at a table.  $\binom{8}{3}$ choices.  One will be youngest and one will be oldest.  Choose whether the oldest sits to the right or the left of the youngest: $2$ choices.  From those remaining, pick two to sit together: $\binom{5}{2}$ choices, giving $\binom{8}{3}\binom{5}{2}\cdot 2 = 1120$, similarly first case can be done in $\binom{8}{4}3!=420$ ways, giving final total $420+1120+420=1960$

Comment: You are looking for Stirling numbers of the first kind $\left[8\atop 5\right]$ See [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) for a table of values and more info. There is a simple recursion $\left[n\atop k\right]=\left[n-1\atop k-1\right]+(n-1)\left[n-1\atop k\right]$ because Alan can sit either on a table on his own in $\left[n-1\atop k-1\right]$ ways or on the right of any of the remaining $n-1$ seated students in $\left[n-1\atop k\right]$ ways.

Comment: @JMoravitz: So are Permutations the wrong tool here?

Comment: Permutations are fine., you just need to be careful to phrase things in a very specific and correct fashion.  I just find it easier to phrase things using combinations

Comment: @JMoravitz: I would really appreciate if you could show me also a version with permutations.

Comment: Your version is correct except for it is missing a division by $3!$ for your third case which accounts for the fact that the three groups with $2$ people each are otherwise indistinguishable.  Note $2520\cdot \frac{1}{3!}=1120$.  I prefer using combinations and referring to "youngest" members of groups because we don't need to use division in order to correct the counts.